# How to read mixed type data to 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I got file and I want to load the data in to 2D array.
The data is mixed type, str and float.
I want to load the data into two dimensional array
which each type will fit.
Is There an elegant short way to do that in python?

Data example:

```
M,0.455,0.365,0.095,0.514,0.2245,0.101,0.15 
M,0.35,0.265,0.09,0.2255,0.0995,0.0485,0.07  
F,0.53,0.42,0.135,0.677,0.2565,0.1415,0.21
```

```
train_x = np.genfromtxt('train_x.txt', dtype=None)
```

```
[[M,0.455,0.365,0.095,0.514,0.2245,0.101,0.15 ], [M,0.35,0.265,0.09,0.2255,0.0995,0.0485,0.07],
[F,0.53,0.42,0.135,0.677,0.2565,0.1415,0.21]]
```

Comment: I can't understand, doesn't your example works? It looks like the output is 2D array. Regardless the example, have you considered to work with Pandas library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = []
with open('train_x.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        out.append([float(num) if n>0  else num for n, num in enumerate(l.split(',')) ])
print(out)
```

this will get what you want:

```
[['M', 0.455, 0.365, 0.095, 0.514, 0.2245, 0.101, 0.15], ['M', 0.35, 0.265, 0.09, 0.2255, 0.0995, 0.0485, 0.07], ['F', 0.53, 0.42, 0.135, 0.677, 0.2565, 0.1415, 0.21]]
```

2D array. the first is `str` type, and other elements are `float` type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But I wanted to know if there's any way to do that while avoiding for loops.

Comment: welcome.  if you find it helpful, you can also give a up vote to my answer. :)